# QGis problem with raster transparent

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity

I am new to QGIS. I found the problem impossible to solve the parts of raster data that are in TIFF format should be made transparent. What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

I did not understand what specific question you have, since you only described your problem.
I m quite new to GIS but I think I may be able to help.
Can you please form a clear question that requires a clear answer?
Note* I know that this is rather a comment than an answer, but I m currently still unable to comment.

Edit:
Ok; If I get you right you want to achieve to make parts of your Raster(that is in TIFF Format) transparent.
Actually this is quite simple;RasterLayer->right click->Properties->global Transparency.
Here you can adjust the value. If you need it for specific areas only use the clipping method.
(Menue->Raster->Extraction->Clipper).
Hope this helps.

Comment: You get my right,I tray your method bat i can not make parts of my Raster image (bleck parts) transparent .Can You sent me a specific what to do step by step .

Comment: What exactly did not work?
I mean; Did you find the option to set the Transparency in the layer options?

Answer (score 0):

The link below seems to be a similar question

It gives a step by step guide to doing so.

[How to make transparent the background of a topographic map in QGis 1.8.0?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/how-to-make-transparent-the-background-of-a-topographic-map-in-qgis-1-8-0)