# Remove white background in Raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm sure this is a very simple task, I have a black and white basemap and i would like to remove the white from it in the latest version QGIS.

There are setting in layer properties and bands etc, but I don't know how to do it and have been unable to find a good explanation. The answer i found was for an earlier version of QGIS and the dialog box has changed!!

Comment: Are you saying the white are the NULL values? So the part of the raster that does not contain any useful information?

Comment: Hey Matt, would you be able to link to the old question to see if this is a duplicate. Maybe the old answer can be updated for the latest version of QGIS.

Answer (score 7):

This may only apply in recent versions of QGIS, but an easier option I have found is to:

•   Go to Layer properties>Transparency>Custom Transparency Options and click ‘Add Values From Display’ (the arrow with a question mark) to auto-populate a new line
•   Then click apply

Make sure the ‘Transparency band’ dropdown is set to ‘None’, unless you want to lose pixels from the remainder of the raster as well. Works best for solid blocks of colour.

Answer (score 5):

With the identify tool, click on a white part of the raster and look for the value.

Then `rightclick -> Properties -> Transparency` tab, add this value to the NODATA section as an additional NODATA value.

Comment: AndreJ, when i choose the unwanted value, i also change a lot of important detail in the raster. How can i choose to remove only the white area?

Comment: @newGIS I think this is worth opening a new question. You may link to this question.

Comment: You can now bypass this second step: in the Transparency tab, click on 'Add values from display' (second button from the top on the right-hand side). 

Then click over the colour which you want to remove. 

Then click apply. 

Unless the background you want to remove is a single pure colour though, you will need to repeat this at least once until you reach a satisfactory result.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the transparency, you can clip the raster by the mask layer. very important to mark those two options so the clip will be accurate:

[image]

see my answer in

[Remove unwanted black area around clipped raster in QGIS 2.18](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247787/remove-unwanted-black-area-around-clipped-raster-in-qgis-2-18)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar transparency problem but got lots of 'near' whites. To rectify this:

1. Under Symbology: "Max"ed the three bands to 240
2. Under Symbology: Changed "Contrast enhancement" to Stretch to MinMax
3. Under Transparency: Add 1 row with "RGB Trans" to 255,255,255,100.
4. Apply and adjust max band as necessary.

[image: Symbology settings to modify]

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click Layer >> Properties >> Style >> and select "Inverted Polygons"

Answer (score 0):

@JimS-W's answer. Totally awesome. I had a raw raster image which I had already clipped to a polygon using masked layer extraction. I was struggling on how to transparent out the blacked out background. This method worked perfectly to remove the clipped remainder.

On that note, what I usually do is use 'Geoscience' plug-in which has a few options in it's taskbar menu (the 2 icons are a white or black half-box checkered square). Use those.

Comment: Please don't add thanks as an answer. Only post full answers to the question as an answer.